# Can't view more than 500 Item on DVWP

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

My list has about 1000 items (can be more later during year). I've done Data View Web Part based on that list. The problem is that I can't view on page more than 500 items, i get an error

```
    Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
    Correlation ID:e38ca748-57ca-46a8-9a11-40cd02b71810
```

Has anyone such problem?

Need your help ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolved my issue

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2012/03/07/xslt-and-timeout-problem-when-transforming-runs-more-than-one-second.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 0):

List Throttling

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8723.sharepoint-2010-best-practices-list-throttling.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/pfemike/archive/2012/08/28/disable-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling-at-the-list-level.aspx

Comment: I appreciate the answer. The view "All Items" can display over 1000 items. And my DVWP can't. I don't think that the reason is throttling. (but i tried to disable it, but DVWP still doesn't display more than 500 items)....  I'm not sure but can this be the solution? see link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2012/03/07/xslt-and-timeout-problem-when-transforming-runs-more-than-one-second.aspx?Redirected=true